# Is this a possible attack?

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving all the search inputs into my database table and analyzing user behavior. Today i encountered this

```
'"><svg/onload=confirm(/openbugbounty/)>
```

Is this a sign of someone trying to attack my site? Please throw some light.

Comment: It is possible it's somebody attempting (or seeing if it is vulnerable to) a XSS attack, but with the given amount of info, who knows.

Comment: Maybe it's a new emoji :-). Or an attempted javascript injection attack. Since you are already monitoring your inputs, I'm assuming you are sanitizing them so that such a pitiful attack would be unsuccessful. That should be your main source of protection.

Comment: Specifically, it's someone's attempt to get some rep on https://www.openbugbounty.org/

Comment: Thanks! Yes, i am using the mysqli_real_escape_string() before the sql operation. Dont know why someone would want to downvote the question. I did search on my question before posting to see if this was a duplicate. Stackoverflow is not a very friendly place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an attempted javascript injection attack.